# Delete task from task scheduler based on userid powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to find tasks which runs using SYSTEM and delete rest of the tasks running using any other account

[image]

I was trying to find the job first, then unregister, but not getting any filters to do that.

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "SPOC_Inventory"
```

Need help in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (without -whatif):

```
PS C:\> Get-ScheduledTask SPOC_Inventory | ? {($_.Principal.UserId -ne "SYSTEM")}| Unregister-ScheduledTask -WhatIf
```

Enjoy
tom

Comment: It appears that this does the opposite of what the OP asked for. It would unregister all tasks of SYSTEM, rather then the "rest".

Comment: You are right. I changed -eq to -ne.

Comment: @TomG: Thanks for the response. but I want to keep the tasks for SYSTEM and unregister rest of them

Comment: But take care not to delete a lot of tasks which are necessary to keep the system running!